# Correctly interpreting numpy shapes

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I’m very new to the numpy library in python and want to understand the basics better. Given a numpy array:

```
array_example = np.array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
                           [4, 5, 6, 7]],

                          [[0, 1, 2, 3],
                           [4, 5, 6, 7]],

                          [[0 ,1 ,2, 3],
                           [4, 5, 6, 7]]])
```

`array_example.ndim` prints out 3.
**My understanding:**
The shape of this numpy array is (3, 2, 4) because I have visualised the shape property as denoting, number of elements in each dimension, or along each axis. In this case, an array of 3 matrices (along axis 0), 2 rows along axis 1 and 4 elements in each row, along axis 2. Basically, the first element in the shape tuple for 3D arrays should denote the number of matrices in the list.

**However**, as per the docs, while analysing an image(https://numpy.org/numpy-tutorials/content/tutorial-svd.html), on opening an image as a numpy array, the shape returned is (768, 1024, 3), which should be read as 3 arrays (here the last item in the tuple denotes the number of matrices) each of shape (768, 1024).

Is there a possible way of understanding multi-dimensional numpy arrays that satisfy both logics?

Comment: The tutorial only shows `arr[:,:,0]` or the whole image.   The last, 3, dimension is 'channels', one for each color.  Abstractly each dimension is the same; it's only in display that we talk about 3 matrices, or 3 channels.

Answer (score 1):

Both logics are valid, but they fail to grasp the core of `ndarray`'s or `n`-dimensional arrays. You say that `(3, 2, 4)` is "a list of 3 matrices of 2x4", but this is just **one** possible interpretation. Other interpretations are:

- `(3, 2, 4)` is a list of two 3x4 matrices
- `(3, 2, 4)` is a list of four 3x2 matrices
- `(3, 2, 4)` is a 3x2 matrix of 4-element arrays
- etc.

The way in which you interpret an `n`-dimensional array all depends on your use case, in particular *how you are accessing it*. For example, your interpretation satisfies the following for loop.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(3,2,4)

for i in range(A.shape[0]):
   print(A[i,:,:])
```

But slicing is wonderful because you can access any dimension independently. For example, if you interpret the matrix as a list of two 3x4 matrices, your for loop would look like:

```
for i in range(A.shape[1]):
   print(A[:,i,:])
```

You can always convert the image matrix you mention to *your* interpretation by reshaping it, as dimensions can be swapped freely in `n`-dimensional arrays. For example, to make your second interpretation of `n`-dimensional arrays consistent with your first one, you could do

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(768, 1024, 3)
A = A.transpose(2, 0, 1)

print(A.shape) # (3, 768, 1024)
```

**tl;dr all interpretations are fine, but they are just *interpretations* and should not be expected to be consistent with every use case.**

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is completely valid and correct.
np.dim returns you the number of array dimensions (axes), and np.shape returns you the size of each axis.

So about the np.array representation of an RGB image, it is in the form (width, height, channels). As you can see the channels = 3 is the last dimension which sure does not have any critical impact on the underlying data and you can transpose to (channels, width, height) for example.
Now this can be read simply as the pixel coordinates (with the first two axes) then its channels (the third axis).